# Itree DataType in java

Tags: java, postgresql

I am using Postgresql Database. I used datatype ITree for TreeStructure. For this which datatype can i use in java?

I want Itree mapping in java object.

Can anybody have solution for this? Please share with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An [ITree](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ltree.html) is a way of "*representing labels of data stored in a hierarchical tree-like structure*". There is no similar data structure built-in to Java (or most languages). A graph library such as Guava's [`common.graph`](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/GraphsExplained) might work, depending on your use-case, otherwise you'll probably want to implement what you need yourself.